# google-cloud-storage distribution not found despite being installed in venv

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

As in the title, when running the appserver I get a DistributionNotFound exception for `google-cloud-storage`:

> File "/home/[me]/Desktop/apollo/lib/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 867, in resolve
>       raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
>   DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-storage' distribution was not found and is required by the application

Running `pip show google-cloud-storage` finds it just fine, in the site packages dir of my venv.  Everything seems to be in order with `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"` too; the cloud SDK dir is in there too, if that matters.

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Not a great answer, but I was able to resolve this by install globally even though it was already installed in my venv

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was that both `google-cloud-storage` and `pkg_resources` need to be in the same directory.

It sounds like your `google-cloud-storage` is in venv and your `pkg_resources` is in the `lib` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing `google-cloud-storage` to the user site using the [`--user`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site) flag.

```py
  pip install google-cloud-storage --user
```